# javascript live text highlighter like diigo.com

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to make a live text highlighter in javascript/jquery? with most script ive seen, you have to select the text first then click highlight. how does diigo.com do it?

Comment: Don't assume that everyone has seen that, you should either provide a link to that or provide an screenshot.

Comment: here's a video explaining how it's used http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gfYFZDsjkU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple javascript can not provide functionality like diigo.com.
You need to write browser plugins.

This type of plugins are called BHO (Browser Helper Object)
Creating BHO need some experience and understanding of COM.

See the examples below

[Exaple 1](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/shell/2find.aspx)

[Exaple 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/BHOinCPP.aspx)

[Example 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Attach_BHO_with_C_.aspx)

Comment: Looks very IE specific to me.

Comment: @Lisa: I think mostly. Same as for plugins for Firefox: JavaScript and some way to define the UI (in this case XUL).